# Current limiter for Stepper motor can't go over 0.90?

Tags: voltage, resistors, stepper-motor, multimeter

I have a chip `a4988` with SMD resistor code R100. I calculated a `VREF` value for my stepper motor like this

```
1.8A * 8 * 0.1 => 1.44
```

1.8 are stepper motor Amps

0.1 ohm is a value for SMD R100 resistor.

So I set my `multimeter` to `20V` mode and trying to adjust and measure a value on the `a4988` chip, but when I rotate a screw on the chip over a 0.90 value, it goes back to 0.01, does it means, it can't go beyond the 0.90 value?

[image]

Comment: Since you are using a chip post the schematic and label the test points where you made your measurements.  What is your reference for your calculation, if from a data sheet post a link to it. How are you getting rid of the heat (heatsink)?

Comment: Which stepper motor, and what voltage are you running it on?

Comment: I'm using NEMA17 3.57V 1.8A recommended voltage (8V~35V2A) and 12V 1.5A AC Adapter

Comment: There shouldn't be a screw on the chip.

Comment: I mean that stuff on the picture on the right side - the `plus` shaped something you can rotate with driver

Comment: thats the current limiter

Answer (score 0):

The correct formula is:

$$I_{trip}=\dfrac{V_{ref}}{8\cdot R_s}$$

Vref is being adjusted by potentiometer. Your formula for Vref:

```
1.8A * 8 * 0.1ohm => 1.44V
```

It depends on supply voltage Vdd and the resistor/potentiometer values to determine Vref.